# store string and grab with JSON

Tags: asp.net, json

```
    <script>
               function ShowCommentBox() {
                    $("#dialog").dialog({ modal: true }); 
                }

                function GrabDetails() {
                    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"name":"John"}');
                    $("#item").val(obj.name);
                }  
    </script>

  <div id="dialog" title="Comments"  style="display:none;">
     <table class="detailstable FadeOutOnEdit">
         <tr>
            <th>Item</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><asp:Label ID="ItemIdLabel" Text="item" runat="server"/></td>
         </tr>
     </table> 
    </div>

<input id="SubmitCommentsToInvoice" type="button" value="Comments" onclick="ShowCommentBox()" />
```

In my asp.net project when the user clicks the 'Comments' button the div appears containing the label.
I'm trying to use JSON to display the string "John" - stored in them #item object in the 'GrabDetails()'

Then in the label text="" How do I pull across the value stored in the #item object.

Thanks

Comment: `$("#item")...` implies that there is an html element with `id="item"` - I don't see it in html you showed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#item` is an ID selector in jQuery, which there is no element here with ID "item". Also, `<asp:Label />` renders from the server as html in a different way. However, it appears you are not using this label on the server side at all? if this is the case i would just make an html element like

```
<td id="WhereNameGoes"></td>
```

then

```
function GrabDetails() {
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"name":"John"}');
    $("#WhereNameGoes").text(obj.name);
    // this still needs to be called somewhere, perhaps in ShowCommentBox()?
}
```

jQuery `$.val()` is more for `<input />` elements